# How to use the Linux driver for a Huion drawing tablet

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet

So I recently got a Huion 580 drawing tablet. It has a Linux driver but I have no idea how to use it. According to the email I got from the company it said that if I had Linux kernel 3.12.2 or above no other action would be required but I use Ubuntu 10.04. (To be honest I'm not exactly sure what a kernel is. I'm not new to Linux either, I just don't know much about it.) I don't know anything about this kind of stuff, so if you could explain it to me in a way even a four year old could understand, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal type:

`uname -r`

It will tell you the kernel version you are using.If it says, for example, 3.13.0-44-generic - It means your kernel version is higher than 3.12.2. If it shows number less than 3.12.2 , for example 3.12.1 or 3.11.5 it means you have to use the driver.

If your kernel version is higher most probably the drivers are already built into the kernel.

Otherwise you should install the driver.